# Return value if no data exist in a list sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a list of barcode and want to get the InvtID with Bookcode as a column. I want if there is no barcode exists then it will return 'no data' as well in the list. This is my current query but it only display the list of exist barcode only.

```
> WITH cte AS (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Barcode ORDER BY
 InvtID Asc) rid FROM InvtCust WHERE Barcode In('123','9789830093697','9789830093727',)) SELECT InvtID,
 BOOKCODE = coalesce(InvtID, 'Bookcode not found') FROM cte WHERE rid =
 1 UNION SELECT InvtID = '', BOOKCODE = 'Bookcode not found' WHERE NOT
 EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CTE)
```

I know there's a lot of question regarding this matter. But I really couldnt solve mine. I have tried these none of it working.

```
    SELECT isnull((SELECT [InvtID] 
    FROM InvtCust WHERE Barcode IN('123','9789830093819')),'No bookcode found') 
    AS InvtID  

    Select case when s.InvtID IS NOT NULL Then s.InvtID else 'no data' end as Bookcode
        from (Select InvtID as InvtID FROM InvtCust  WHERE Barcode IN('123')) R
        Left Join InvtCust  s ON s.InvtID = R.InvtID 

select expr1, InvtID from (
    select *,ROW_NUMBER() over(order by isrealrow asc) rownum from (
        select COUNT(*) as expr1, InvtID, 1 as isrealrow from [DANNY].[dbo].[InventoryCustomer]
        where Barcode in ('ean','9789830093819','9789830093826','9789830094205') 
        Group by InvtID 
        union select 0,'No bookcode found',0 as isrealrow
        )b
 )c
 where isrealrow=1 or rownum=1

    IF NOT EXISTS (Select InvtID From InvtCust  WHERE Barcode in ('123')) 
      Begin SELECT 'Bookcode not found' as Bookcode end
    ELSE
      SELECT InvtID From InvtCust WHERE Barcode in ('123')
```

Comment: Please share the table structure with sample data to help you in this query

Comment: Also need clarify on your question before providing you solution. Do you if there is no barcode records found in the InvtCust then 'barcode no found' will be returned else query will return the InvID, barcode as columns

Answer (score 0):

In my view, it is better to put all your logic inside stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourProcedure
AS
    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Results
    create table #Results
    (
        InvtID INT,
        BookCode VARCHAR(255)
    ) 

    WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
    *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Barcode ORDER BY InvtID Asc) rid 
    FROM InvtCust 
    WHERE Barcode In('123','9789830093697','9789830093727'))
    INSERT INTO #Results
    (
         InvtID,
         BookCode
    ) 
    SELECT InvtID,
    BOOKCODE = coalesce(InvtID, 'Bookcode not found') 
    FROM cte WHERE rid = 1 
    UNION 
    SELECT 
      InvtID = ''
    , BOOKCODE = 'Bookcode not found' 
    WHERE NOT
    EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM CTE)


    DECLARE @rows INT = 0;
    SELECT @rows = COUNT(1) FROM #Results
    SELECT @rows

    IF @rows > 0
       BEGIN 
        SELECT 
        *
        #Results
       END
    ELSE 
       SELECT 'No Data'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

This query will give you the desired results. Am Assuming you have comma separated barcode list which you want to search in the table, If the query will find that barcode in the table it will return the barcode along with the InvtID else it will return the message 'no barcode found' for that record instead of InvtID .

**For SQL server 2016 or Above**

```
with BarcodeList as
(
    select value as barcode
    from string_split('aaaa,bbbb,cccc' , ',')
)
Select isnull(cast(InvtID as varchar), 'No barcode found') InvtID, b.Barcode From BarcodeList b left outer join InvtCust i
 on  b.barcode = i.barcode
```

**Note:** string_split function used in this query supported in SQL server 2016 onwards. If you are using SQL server below 2016 then you should create & use the custom split function as shown below.

**For Below SQL server 2016**

**Custom Split Function**

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[String_Split] 
( 
    @string NVARCHAR(MAX), 
    @delimiter CHAR(1) 
) 
RETURNS @output TABLE(value NVARCHAR(MAX) 
) 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @start INT, @end INT 
    SELECT @start = 1, @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string) 
    WHILE @start < LEN(@string) + 1 BEGIN 
        IF @end = 0  
            SET @end = LEN(@string) + 1

        INSERT INTO @output (value)  
        VALUES(SUBSTRING(@string, @start, @end - @start)) 
        SET @start = @end + 1 
        SET @end = CHARINDEX(@delimiter, @string, @start)

    END 
    RETURN 
END
Go
```

**Actual query**

```
with BarcodeList as
(
    select  value as barcode
        from dbo.[String_Split]('aaaa,bbbb,cccc' , ',')
)
Select isnull(cast(InvtID as varchar), 'No barcode found') InvtID, b.Barcode From BarcodeList b left outer join InvtCust i
 on  b.barcode = i.barcode
```